# How to we explicitly get that #(G/H) = #G/#H from lagrange's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ group, $H\subset G$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then we have from Lagrange's Theorem that

$\#(G/H) = \frac{\#G}{\#H}$

Why is this the case? The proof I've seen constructs all the possible (disjoint) left cosets as follows: take $g_1,...,g_n$ the elements of $G$ that form distinct cosets for $g_iH$. Then $G = g_1H\cup ... \cup g_nH$, but I'm not seeing our desired result in this.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) This is for *finite* groups. (2) Because each coset has exactly $\#H$ elements.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh of course. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $\#g_jH=\#H$. So, since the union $g_1H\cup g_2H\cup\ldots\cup g_nH$ is a disjoint union,$$
\#G=n\times\#H=\#(G/H)\times\#H.
$$

Comment: Can you talk me through how you deduce that $n = \#(G/H)$?

Comment: *By definition* the set $G/H$ is $\{g_1H,g_2H,\ldots,g_nH\}$, which is a set with $n$ elements.